# error with sql syntax where having

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

Just trying to make this query work, but it is a bit difficult for me..

```
SELECT
    *, 
  COUNT(*) AS total FROM_UNIXTIME(consume_time,'%Y-%m') AS fecha
FROM
    coupon
HAVING
    fecha = '2016-07'
GROUP BY
    partner_id
```

Comment: wrong use of `HAVING` and found syntax error too. Try this: `SELECT
 *, 
 COUNT(*) AS total,
  DATE_FORMAT(`consume_time`,'%Y-%m') AS fecha
FROM coupon
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`consume_time`,'%Y-%m') = '2016-07'
GROUP BY `partner_id``

Comment: is there any error you're getting? what's the problem? it's giving error? data not being returned? correct data not being return?

Comment: Sorry, it gives me unknown column fecha in WHERE clause

Comment: [**Try this**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/22671117/)

Comment: you used this: `fecha = '2016-07'` meaning, you're telling your mysql to return data where (although it's wrong use of having as 1000111 said) `fecha = '2016-07'` but fecha is just an alias (`AS fecha`). you have to use the column that really exists in the table.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're missing a `,` in the select list, between `AS total` and `FROM_UNIXTIME`.
2. `HAVING` filters grouped sets, whereas `WHERE` filters records before they are grouped—in this case you want the latter, however aliases like `fecha` are not available when the `WHERE` clause is evaluated.  You therefore need to repeat the underlying expression in the `WHERE` clause:

   ```sql
   WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(consume_time,'%Y-%m') = '2016-07'
   ```

   However, this approach would not be sargable—better to convert your literal to a range upon which `consume_time` can be directly filtered (especially if the table has an index thereon):

   ```sql
   WHERE consume_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-07-01')
     AND consume_time <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-08-01')
   ```

   Even better still to store `consume_time` as a temporal datatype that MySQL understands, e.g. [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) (which happens to be stored internally as a Unix timestamp), rather than a mere integer—then you'd be able to do away with the conversion functions altogether:

   ```sql
   WHERE consume_time >= '2016-07-01'
     AND consume_time <  '2016-08-01'
   ```
3. Since you're grouping by `partner_id`, the values in any resultset column that are not functionally dependent thereon will be indeterminate.  This probably is not what you want.  Did you really mean to select all columns but group by `partner_id`?